# Readable names for python objects as dictionary keys

Tags: python, object, dictionary, key, names

In Python, using custom objects as dictionary keys can give pretty unreadable output. This is a small example:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self,foo,bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

item = myClass(1,2)
myDict = {}
myDict[item] = 10 

print myDict
{<__main__.myClass object at 0x01998FD0>: 10}
```

This dictionary will become unreadable if there are many objects. I would like it to show the name of the object instead:

```
{'item':10}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) for `myClass`:

```
>>> class myClass(object):
...     def __init__(self,foo,bar):
...         self.foo = foo
...         self.bar = bar
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'myClass({0.foo},{0.bar})'.format(self)
... 
>>> item = myClass(1,2)
>>> item
myClass(1,2)
>>> myDict = {}
>>> myDict[item] = 10
>>> myDict
{myClass(1,2): 10}
```

Comment: or `__str__` to use with `print` statement

Comment: Yea, this would be a reasonable solution. Mind explaining what the '0' object means? Would it also be possible to refer to it as its given name 'item'?

Comment: @Forzaa, `0` means the first argument passed to [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format) method.

Comment: @Forzaa, this is special `str` formatting, you can find more about this here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings with examples.

Comment: The input for my object are functions, which are again referred to <function blabla at 0x0190D6B0>. This means I also have to create __repr__ for each function as well. While in general __repr__ is nice, I don't find it the best solution for my problem at the moment.

Comment: @Forzaa, How about using `self.foo.__name__`?